# Mysterious Incoming/Outgoing Packets on my Wireless Connection

Tags: wifi

Right now I am connecting to my work server as usual and during my connection through the VPN I always monitor the network ping through terminal and its always between 70-90. It usually never goes up beyond that, but lately I have noticed that it will sometimes go up to 1000-3000 then timeout and disconnect me for few minutes until I attempt to reconnect. Everyone in my home who uses the connection has not been engaging in unusual download or upload activity (eg. bittorrent etc).

When I disconnected the server that manages my local network at home, the problem seems to be solved for a while then it comes back, as I check my router to I find unfamiliar Mac address on my network. I am setting up a MAC address white-list to block non home wireless connections. I think this should be sufficient to solve this problem, but how might I monitor incoming/outgoing packets on my network if the white-list is ineffective.

(I'm using a Linksys E1000 router with Cisco Firmware Version: 2.1.01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This May not be the answer but it won't let me comment.*

Sounds like you are concerning about if unauthorized person had access to your network, and according to that you, you trying to **Filter MAC Addresses** If I am correct, To maybe secure your network? this won't solve your issue as *Filtering* is not a security feature!

MAC (Media Access Control) or sometimes called physical addresses or hardware addresses. Any device has MAC Address and it can communicate with any router as long as it knows the appropriate pass-phrase. with *White-list* When a device connects to a router, it always receives a specific IP address if it has a matching **MAC address**. Else it refuse the connection.

However, MAC address filtering, is more of a network administration feature. It won’t protect you against attackers trying to get onto your network. Therefore, it will allow you to choose which devices are allowed online. Even if necessary to be online * **MAC Addresses** can be easily [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) in so many operating system's specially with such nice tool as Kali Linux.

There is tons of packet-sniffer's out there and one of the best is [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) Where as you said to monitor your network, but the issue still remain if you are not there to monitor it. There is one way around that where you can find a way to set-up network alert to scan and log sniffed packets in certain time of the day or when this alert is triggered somehow according to your preferences.

Comment: This wouldn't fit in as a comment